# use @at-root and & in list of selectors

Tags: sass

I have a CSS I try to move to SASS with many structures like

```
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
...
}
```

With this:

```
 .btn-primary {
    ...
    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active,
    &.active,
    .open .dropdown-toggle#{&} {
```

I obviously get:

```
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.btn-primary .open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
...
}
```

But I seem not to be allowed to use `@at-root`:

```
 .btn-primary {
    ...
    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active,
    &.active,
    @at-root .open .dropdown-toggle#{&} {
```

Because SASS expects a selector after the comma and gets an @...

Comment: @Brett DeWoody: I didn't add the CSS tag for a reason. The question is all about SASS. Of course, SASS has to do with CSS, but for that reason every SASS question would need a CSS tag - and that can not be the idea. On the other hand: this question could not have been answered by anyone who only knows CSS - and everybody who knows SASS knows CSS. So: The question is a pure SASS question and doesn't need the CSS tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@at-root` directive cannot be used this way.  It is intended to be applied the complete selector, not an individual selector in the list.  Since your selectors are both classes, you can just reposition your parent selector to the beginning rather than try to append it to the end:

```
.btn-primary {
    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active,
    &.active,
    .open &.dropdown-toggle {
      color: red;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
  color: red;
}
```

If it absolutely must be at the end (eg. you're using an element or pseudo selector), the simplest solution is to just use extends:

```
%common {
    color: red;
}

.btn-primary {
    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active,
    &.active {
        @extend %common;
    }

    @at-root .open .dropdown-toggle#{&} {
        @extend %common;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: red;
}
```