# SASS - "elements inside" selector

Tags: css, sass

Consider a few selectors that I specify a color for. I'd like them to have a different color, when they are inside some other element. SCSS:

```css
.a, .b, .c {
  color: white;
}

.black {
  .a, .b, .c {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Can it be written shorter (wihout repeating the selectors)? I tried to use the `@at-root`,

```css
.a, .b, .c {
  color: white;
  @at-root .black #{&} {
      color: black;
  }
}
```

but the result is not as expected:

```css
.a, .b, .c {
  color: white;
}
.black .a, .b, .c {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: hi, interesting, this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902927/use-at-root-and-in-list-of-selectors

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mixin for the abccolor then run that through the black class and add your own colour variable in the parameter:

```
@mixin abccolour($color) {
    .a, .b, .c {
       color: $color;
    }
}

@include abccolour(white);

.black {
    @include abccolour(black);
}
```

which gives us this:

```
.a, .b, .c {
    color: white;
}

.black .a, .black .b, .black .c {
    color: black;
}
```

Then you can reuse that abccolor mixin elsewhere. I tested this mixin using the [Online SCSS Compiler](https://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php).